# array of counters in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to count letters in a file with this text :

> "abbcccddddeeeeeffffff........zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"

I want to create an array of counters:
in order to do this:

```
count[0] = 1 /* # of a's */
count[1] = 2 /* # of b's */

/* ... */

count[25] = 26 /* # of z's */
```

this my first approach

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main() {
    int count[26];
    int i;
    int c;
    for(i=0; i<26; i++){
       count[i] = 0;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(c)) {
         count[i] ++;
       }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can convert the ASCII value of '''c''' to an index using: '''c-'a' ''' or '''c-'A' ''', depending on the case (upper/lower) of the input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you hand-typed your first approach here. It doesn't much matter for this specific problem, but people (well, _me_) get ornery and start down-voting when the code being discussed here isn't the actual code you're testing. (Note the `counr[i]` -- that cannot compile.) Copy and paste your code. Don't retype from memory. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is to turn the character into an index in the array. You can do this by subtracting `'a'` from the character and that will be the index. For example:

```
'a' - 'a' == 0
'b' - 'a' == 1
...
'z' - 'a' == 25
```

And with that index, you know what element to increment. It might be good to do a check on this index, so that `c - 'a' >= 0 && c - 'a' < 26` so you don't index outside the bounds of the array.

Also, make sure to initialise every element of the array to `0` so that the count of each character starts at 0 at first, like this:

```
int count[26] = { };
```

This will set all the elements to `0`.

You also might want to use `tolower(c) - 'a'` instead of just `c = 'a'`, so that it will make the letter lowercase whether it is lowercase or not so that the array contains the count of both uppercase and lowercase versions of the letters, for example both `'a'` and `'A'` will increment `count[0]`. But that is up to you and how you want your program to work.

Furthermore, your code doesn't read a file, it uses `getchar` which reads from `stdin` (the console). Take a look at [`fopen`](http://www.friedspace.com/fopen.html), [`fclose`](http://www.friedspace.com/fclose.html) and [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fread.html) to read a file and process its contents.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should do homework by yourself.

Anyway, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() 
{
    int count[26];
    int i, c;
    for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
       count[i] = 0;
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(c)) 
        {
            ++count[tolower(c) - 'a'];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: "I think you should do homework by yourself... so here is the answer. huh?  Also, it is broken for uppercase characters.